# How to prove that for any $c∈C$, $HW = HD(c)$

Tags: coding-theory

If there's a Binary Linear Block Code. 
Let $HW$ be the set  of all distinct Hamming weights that codewords of $C$ may have. 
Let $HD(c)$ be the set of all distinct Hamming distances between $c$ and any codeword. 

Prove: $HW = HD(c)$ for any $c∈C$.

I think it results from the generator matrix, but still haven't managed anything out. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $c \in C$.

$$
HD(c)
= \{d_H(x, c) \mid x \in C\}
= \{w_H(x - c) \mid x \in C\}
$$

A vector space is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so $x - c \in C$ if and only if $x \in C$. Thus

$$
\{w_H(x - c) \mid x \in C\}
= \{w_H(x) \mid x \in C\}
= HW.
$$